# Exam and Ramadan coinsides

Tags: sawm

I have a question regarding fasting.

I feel strain in my kidney area during fasting. Also, I have a target of sitting for GRE exam in the last week of June which is being seriously hampered by fasting as I can't study while fasting as my brain doesn't work (I can't focus) when [my stomach is empty](https://campuskitchens.org/2016/08/studying-on-an-empty-stomach/). Also, it creates problems in my daily routine. I already have insomnia for which I am taking medications.

But, I am scared of skipping my fasting in Ramadan as it reminds me of death and afterlife.

Is there any way I can legally skip the fasting in Ramadan? What does Islam say about my problems?

Comment: As far as I know in the last week of June we will have the month of Shawwal not Ramadan! So why should you worry about fasting then?

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I need to get prepared for the exam or what?

Comment: Ramadan ends in middle of June you say your exam is in the end preparing for the exam can be done at times were you are in best mood (in the morning) and after the maghrib etc. you want an excuse not to fast for your exam preparation this is weird.

Answer (score 3):

Fasting is mandatory for all able-bodied adults during the Month of Ramadhan. Keep in mind that Shaytan will try to prevent you from fulfilling this obligation through fears and worries about your health. If you feel strain in your kidneys during fasting, you should get it checked out with a doctor to make sure it's not just provoked by fear. If it turns out that fasting really is damaging your kidneys, then this would constitute a valid reason to skip fasting during summer seasons (as the days are longer) and make up for it later on during winters or by giving alms to the poor in exchange for each skipped fast.

As for your exams, it is not a valid excuse to skip fasting as there is no correlation between studying well and a full stomach. I would advise you to recite "la hawl wala quwwata illa billah" (لا حول ولا قوۃ الا باللہ) in order to repel the evil thoughts inspired in our Nafs from Shaytan.

Comment: @Hamza has spoken from the truth. His job was to relay the message which he has. It is upto you to verify it from the Quran and Sunnah. There is no need for ridicule. If you are healthy but desire to skip fasting it is between you and Allah. You are answerable to God for your decisions not him. As far as GRE and your livelihood is concerned, your struggle isn't that great my friend. I have seen laborers who toil all day in the sun yet fast. I know medical residents who work 15+ hours yet fast. The Prophet (SAW) & Sahaba fought a war while fasting.

Comment: With age inshallah you will get wisdom to understand. For now get yourself a doctor's appointment if you really feel pain in your kidneys and consult your parents about Ramadan and your health.

Comment: @Ahmed, `The Prophet (SAW) & Sahaba fought a war while fasting.` --- they didn't have McDonald's back then.